# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined jest.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, undefined

I'm trying to do a pretty basic Flashcard application in react. I'm very new to it so I apologize in advance if my code is riddle with errors, or just poorly done. I am just trying to run a very simple test on my component with jest to see if it renders without crashing. My application runs fine when I just yarn start from the command line but the test keeps failing. Any help would be much appreciated!

CardList component

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from './Card';

export default function CardList({ cards }) {
  return (
    //grid styling so that the app can be responsive no matter the screen size
    <div className="my-grid">
      {cards.map(card => {
        //return card component only re renders unique elements
        return <Card card={card} key={card.id} />
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

` That's the code for the component, then below is the test:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import CardList from './CardList';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<CardList />, div);
});
```

Comment: you did not pass any arguments to the Cardlist constructor, obviously `cards` are undefined

Comment: Pass the `cards` props to the component

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `cards` as a prop of the `CardList` component.

E.g.

`CardList.jsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Card from './Card';

export default function CardList({ cards }) {
  return (
    <div className="my-grid">
      {cards.map((card) => {
        return <Card card={card} key={card.id} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

`Card.jsx`:

```js
export default function Card({ card }) {
  return <div>{card.name}</div>;
}
```

`CardList.test.jsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import CardList from './CardList';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const cards = [{ id: 1, name: 'teresa teng' }];
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<CardList cards={cards} />, div);
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/64817280/CardList.test.jsx (11.207s)
  ✓ renders without crashing (22ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.292s
```